# Не могу понять почему возвращается неверное первое вхождение подстроки

Tags: php

Я пишу следующую функцию:

```
public static function checkTextOnPattern(string $text): string
{
    $result = '';
    $matches = [];
    $text = 'Какой-то текст /Бог Амон!=Истинный Бог/ продолжение какого-то текста или /Да!=Нет/';

    preg_match_all('/\/(.+?)\//', $text, $matches);
    
    if (isset($matches[0])) {
        $offset = 0;
        foreach ($matches[0] as $number => $match) {
            $position = strpos($text, $match, $offset);
            dd($position, mb_substr($text, 0, $position));
        }
    }
    
    dd($matches);
    
    
    return $result;
}
```

Результат выполнения:

27

"Какой-то текст /Бог Амон!=И"

Я не могу понять, почему возвращается неверное первое вхождение подстроки - 27, когда должно быть около 16. Я не знаю какой-то специфики php функции strpos? Почему возвращается не ожидаемое значение?

Comment: Почему вы используете `mb_substr`, но `strpos` не мультибайтовый?

Comment: Потому что не задумался над этим. Спасибо, попробую заменить strpos на mb_substr